# aSourceMapConsumer.eachMapping is not a function

Tags: angular

My Angular project working well in the local system but when I am trying to build a docker image to release changes on azure. it stuck in between. and did not allow me to generate image.

I already tried to upgrade the webpack version, but it won't work.

Comment: Hi, can you paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Also, check if the version of NodeJs is same in the docker image

Comment: Check the below link to see the details 

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IA34iE9lwfQ5dPQK8gBkhCl2JeKpQ4G2

Comment: Not able to generate image it stuck before generating.

Comment: I just get same issue on Angular 11 @KaranEkkawala did u find solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue with an Angular project. And fixed it by the below solution.

The root cause is the incompatibility between `source-map` version in the dependencies.

Hope it helps you.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14587#issuecomment-774081050

[image]